# Memory in Mat becomes invalid throwing SIGSEGV when accessed, how to check for validity?

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault

In multi-threaded program I init Mat using memory location from other object which lives in different thread:

```
GstMapInfo map;
gst_buffer_map(q_inference_buffers.back(), &map, GST_MAP_READ);
cv::Mat frame = (cv::Mat(cv::Size(width, height), CV_8UC3, (char*)map.data));
```

Code is simplistic, `map` object lives in one thread, `frame` is passed for processing in other thread. Situation might happen where object that holds data will get destructed before `frame` is processed. So program gets `SIGSEGV`. There are a few ways I can fix this problem, simplest would be to copy memory which I want to avoid.

Is there a way to tell that data `frame` points to becomes invalid? Like perform a check before accessing it.

EDIT: Mutex is another way to fix it, but it is complex solution which will require flags and locking mutex, cumulative time for which adds up over hours of program work. Im considering it but firstly decided to ask if there are other options.

Comment: Is `map.size == width * heigh * 3`?

Comment: The correct way would be to ensure that `map` does **not** get destructed before `frame` is processed. It's not up to `frame` to query whether the memory it has been given has gone stale; it's up to the programmer to ensure this won't happen.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve it without using synchronisation primitives like mutexes or spin-locks, since data copying most likely is not atomic w.r.t. your hardware. With modern c++ (since c++11) adding a mutex shouldn't be a big deal

Comment: On your question on if it is possible to check if the data has become invalid: No, fundamentally it is impossible to look at a pointer and tell if it points at something valid. In the most "lucky/unlucky" case one bit of code will destroy the object pointed to, and then another part of the code will construct a new object of the same type that just happens to be placed in the same address. In this case the thread with the pointer will have no way to tell that the object it is pointing to *now* is not the same as the one it was created to point at.

Comment: X-Y problem. As mentioned above, lifetime of `map` must exceed lifetime of `frame`. Checking the validity of the pointer (even if possible) would be pointless, since with no synchronization, that could happen anytime, even in the middle of some OpenCV function. | It's hard to give any more concrete advice, since we don't see the bigger picture. A proper [mcve] would be required for that.

Comment: Please consider calling `gst_buffer_ref` on the `q_inference_buffers.back()` to extend lifetime of that buffer and own that buffer in another thread. Once the other thread is done with the processing you may destroy cv::Mat object, call `gst_buffer_unmap` and then call `gst_buffer_unref`. I would probably wrap all in a simpel RAII resource class (movable, non-copyable) and create the object and cv::Mat in first thread and move to the other for processing.

Comment: "simplest would be to copy memory which I want to avoid" -- well if you don't need `map` to contain the result (which I guess you don't, since you have this problem), then certainly do that. If you do any significant processing, the overhead should be relatively minor.